# Built one MySQL INSERT using two different arrays using for each

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, insert

I hope someone is able to help me with the problem I'm facing for hours already. I'm trying to built a MySQL INSERT from two arrays. One array ($bms) holds 6 values and the second one holds 3 values (I want to use the array with 3 values inside the INSERT query where I'm using the placeholder *group* right now). Each value of the (group array) needs to be used 2 times. I hope you understand with my example below:

The 2 arrays – always include 6 respectively 3 values:

**Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 3 [2] => 4 [3] => 121 [4] => 13 [5] => 154 ) // *$bms***

**Array ( [0] => 266 [1] => 267 [2] => 268 ) // *group***

The query with foreach loops:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO userlinks (linkpool_id, group, userid) VALUES ";
foreach($bms as $bm) {
    $query .= "('".$bm."', group, '".$userid."'),";
}
echo $query;
```

The output so far:

```
INSERT INTO userlinks (linkpool_id, group, userid) VALUES ('8', group, '19'),('3', group, '19'),('4', group, '19'),('121', group, '19'),('13', group, '19'),('154', group, '19')
```

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO ACHIEVE**:

```
INSERT INTO userlinks (linkpool_id, group, userid) VALUES ('8', '266', '19'),('3', '266', '19'),('4', '267', '19'),('121', '267', '19'),('13', '268', '19'),('154', '268', '19')
```

I really appreciate your help and invested time – awesome community!

Comment: 3x2 = 6, I don't see the problem ?! @RajdeepPaul

Comment: The two first values of `$bms` needs to be associated with the first value of `$group`, the 3rd and 4th of `$bms` with the second of `$group` etc ... So each value of `group` will be used twice.

Comment: @Treast Ah, now it's clear. Perhaps I need some more coffee. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop instead :

```
$query = "INSERT INTO userlinks (linkpool_id, group, userid) VALUES ";

for($i = 0; $i < count($bms); $i++) {
  $j = (int) $i/2; //[0,1] will return 0, [2,3] return 1 etc... 
  $query .= "('".$bms[$i]."', '".$groups[$j]."', '".$userid."'),";
}

rtrim($query, ",");
echo $query;
```

**Edit:** Thanks [@RajdeepPaul](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5517143/rajdeep-paul) for more precision.

Comment: `group` is a MySQL reserved word, encapsulate the table and column names using backticks. Also, remove the trailing `,` from the final query, do `echo rtrim($query, ",");`

Comment: @Treast, ok so I've tried the code you suggested above, but the output looks like this -> 

`INSERT INTO userlinks (linkpool_id, group, userid) VALUES ('8', '', '19'),('3', '', '19'),('4', '', '19'),('121', '', '19'),('13', '', '19'),('154', '', '19')`

How do I assign the value of the groups array to it? I don't get it, sorry.

Comment: My mistake, sorry! Yes the code you provided above works just fine! Thanks a lot!